# How to add a datepicker to a dynamically added div with Jquery with on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a div to a form that I am creating.  I want to do this with the `on()` function, but I cannot seem to make it work.  From what I understand you have to use an event, but is there a way to make an event out of a div being added.  The code that I have been trying is with a "click" event, but that isnt really what I want.  The datepicker is added after the first click, but the buttonImage is not being added at all.  I need it to work on the first click.  Here is the code that I am using right now:

```
  $('#switcher-panel').on('click', 'table tr td input', function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.png"
    });
  });
```

Here is the html that I am using:

```
<table class="table table-hover" data-controller="rank">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" align="left"><h2> Boy Scout Rank</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Requirements</th>
      <th>Completed</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-name="one_li">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
        Req
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="datepicker"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I dont understand how to handle this.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you paste the segment of code relating to you adding the div to the form?

Comment: +1 to the above. Also, can you clarify what is happening with the datepicker, and how it relates to this div? Is the datepicker not appearing until the second click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        showOn:"button", // or "both" if you want the input to trigger the datepicker too
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.png"
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your above code, it doesn't look like you're adding a new `<div />`

If you're not, you shouldn't need to add an event (click) handler - http://jsfiddle.net/ZNR7P/

You should just be able to do:

```
$(function() {

    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

});​
```